# How to run some default commands after firing the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, irb

I need to run a few commands whenever I start my Rails console, like setting up the logger, or to set the time to my time zone.

Right now I'm copying and pasting these commands after Rails is started. Can I write a script to make these commands run automatically after IRB is started?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rails' console is IRB.](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) [IRB supports an .irbrc file](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/irb/rdoc/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Configuration), which contains initialization information and settings.

Read "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123494/whats-your-favourite-irb-trick" and "[My .irbrc for console/irb](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/84414)" for ideas.

Comment: is there a similar thing for rails console ? I m sorry I framed the question incorrectly .

Comment: Rails console is IRB.

Comment: for e.g. when I do rails console .I get a IRB console then I use a command like Time.zone = A.info.time_zone .it sets the Time zone but I want this command to automatically load when I fore my rails c .I even tried rails c command .

Comment: Then put that command in the ~/.irbrc file, or in /path/to/your/rails/app/.irbrc just like the documentation and examples show.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an [extended answer to this in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445793/321583) but the short answer is that if you are [using Rails 3 or above](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/fa98eca75bd8666719bf3d061c87638850a20fe9#diff-dee764b95770b23869cd6ce3351109f5) you can use the console method on YourApp::Application to make it happen:

```
module YourApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    ...

    console do
      Time.zone = A.info.time_zone
    end
  end
end
```