# Rails7 MultiDB switch shard for console

Tags: console, sharding, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm experimenting with rails 7 [multidb sharding](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_multiple_databases.html#horizontal-sharding), and I would like to be able to set the default  shard for a rails console session.

I can use

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(role: :writing, shard: :default) do
  @id = Person.create! # Creates a record in shard default
end
```

but that's quite cumbersome for each command.
Is there any way to set it from the command line, something like

```
shard=shard_one rails c
```

Comment: I looked at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445793/430721 but I don't think it will work in my case, since I need to to run it around the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed this to the following solution because the `db:rollback` tasks didn't work because it had an issue with reading the `database.yml`

`database.yml`

```yaml
development:
  nl:
    <<: *default_database
    database: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_DATABASE_NL") { Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mysql, :database_nl) } %>
  uk:
    <<: *default_database
    database: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_DATABASE_UK") { Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mysql, :database_uk) } %>
```

And add the following in your `application.rb`

```rb
def config.database_configuration
  parsed = super
  default_shard = ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_SHARD') { 'nl' }
  default_shard_config = { "#{default_shard}": parsed[Rails.env].delete(default_shard) }
  parsed[Rails.env] = default_shard_config.merge(parsed[Rails.env])
  parsed
end
```

Now you can still run `DISABLE_SPRING=true DEFAULT_SHARD="uk" rails` but also `bin/rails db:rollback:uk` etc.

Answer (score 1):

The non-block equivalent of `ActiveRecord::Base.connected_to(...) do ... end` is `ActiveRecord::Base.connecting_to(...)`. Since `writing` is the default role, in your case the simplified code is `ActiveRecord::Base.connecting_to(shard: :default)` which will set the active shard until you change it. For example with `ActiveRecord::Base.connecting_to(shard: :other_shard)`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up hacking my `database.yml` file like this

```yaml
<%= ctrys = ['nl','uk']; main = ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_SHARD'){'nl'}; ctrys.delete(main); ctrys.unshift(main);nil %>
development:
  <%= ctrys[0] %>:
    <<: *default_database
    database: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_DATABASE_#{ctrys[0].upcase}") { Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mysql, :"database_#{ctrys[0]}") } %>
  <%= ctrys[1] %>:
    <<: *default_database
    database: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_DATABASE_#{ctrys[1].upcase}") { Rails.application.credentials.dig(:mysql, :"database_#{ctrys[1]}") } %>
```

I can use it like this:

```
~prompt% DISABLE_SPRING=true DEFAULT_SHARD="uk" rails
Loading development environment (Rails 7.0.1)
hvg-web(dev)> ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.db_config.name
=> "uk"
```

(spring will cache it, so disable spring)

this hack does give the test-runner a challenge though:

```
/usr/src/app# rspec
Running via Spring preloader in process 2504
Running via Spring preloader in process 2510
Rails couldn't infer whether you are using multiple databases from your database.yml and can't generate the tasks for the non-primary databases. If you'd like to use this feature, please simplify your ERB.
```

feels hacky, but it works - maybe somebody else can come up with a better plan?